# Particularity of parameter for javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a little question. If I had a  like that :

```
<td id="1003212" class="tabG_numOF donneesOF 1003212" value="1003212" onClick="onClick_celluleID(1003212);">
```

and an other like that :

```
<td id="comp1003254" class="tabG_composant donneesOF 1003254" value="310049063 OMNI SERGE F915 GREGE HDB L1920" onClick="onClick_cellule(310049063OMNISERGEF915GREGEHDBL1920);">
```

Why the next function doesn't work with the second even it work with the first ?

```
function onClick_cellule(t) {
            alert(t);
}
```

? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because `310049063OMNISERGEF915GREGEHDBL1920` will cause a syntax error. I guess you intended it to be a string (notice the quotes):

```
onClick_cellule("310049063OMNISERGEF915GREGEHDBL1920");
```

Literal values in JavaScript can be of type string, number, boolean, array, object, null or undefined. Your value does not parse as any of them, so it causes an error. String literals must be surrounded by quotes, so in the fixed example above we are passing a string literal to the function.

Answer (score 0):

The second identifier is not a valid number, so you need to treat is as a string:

```
onClick_cellule('310049063OMNISERGEF915GREGEHDBL1920');
```

Answer (score 0):

second one is not number try to pass

```
<td id="comp1003254" class="tabG_composant donneesOF 1003254" value="310049063 OMNI SERGE F915 GREGE HDB L1920" onClick="onClick_cellule('310049063OMNISERGEF915GREGEHDBL1920');">
```

Answer (score 0):

The first function take number but the second take string so you should put your taken inside quotes :

```
onClick="onClick_cellule('310049063OMNISERGEF915GREGEHDBL1920');"
```